# Posting a message to UI from business logic

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, mfc

Plot: I have application written as

- UI Layer.
- Business Logic Layer (Static Lib).
- Service Layer.

Communication between UI and Service layer happens via sockets.
`OnInitDialog()` of the main dialog, i am calling the `businessLogic.GetAllModuleInfo();` which will fetch the data from **services** and after that i am  calling `UpdateData(FROM_MEMBERS_TO_CONTROLS);` to update the data on the UI.

**But the data is not getting reflected on UI.**

I just want to know which is the better way to update the UI once the business logic(which is implemented as static lib) data gets changed?

Do I need to post message to UI? If yes, I will not be having the UI handles in the business logic to post message to UI. How to go ahead?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you saying you get your data from business logic but it is not displaying?

Comment: Yes... It is not getting updated.

Comment: Post some more code but it is not clear. Are you using dialog based or SDI/MDI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UpdateData only works for controls that have been mapped to member variables with a DDX_Text statement in DoDataExchange. The IDE helps add these with the 'Add Variable' wizard in the resource editor.